# Running an app in WebStorm on MacOS with Parallels installed

Tags: macos, webstorm, parallels

When I try to run a project from WebStorm 9, I get the following error:

```
The application /User/{Username}/Applications (Parallels)/{{guid}}/...
```

I then click "Fix" and try to specify a custom path to Chrome. After I browse, it shows up as:

```
/Applications/Google Chrome.app
```

Parallels seems to be forcing WebStorm to look for applications in the Parallels folder.

How can I override this behavior in WebStorm?

Comment: When I click on index.html and select "open in browser", that works. Run does not. Does anyone know how to sync the browsers for "open in browser" and "run" in WebStorm 9?

Answer (score 2):

It's a Parallels issue - see http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36#comment=27-70940
Please try the following:
global parallels menu: Virtual Machine -> Configure -> Options tab -> Applications -> uncheck Share Windows applications with Mac

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue and changing Parallels sharing settings was not a good option for me. Fortunately, it can be fixed in WebStorm configuration. Just specify Mac location of Chrome **/Applications/Google Chrome.app** instead of an incorrect one **Google Chrome.app** for the default browser setting in **ide.general.xml**:

```
~/Library/Preferences/WebStorm11/options/ide.general.xml
...
<option name="browserPath" value="/Applications/Google Chrome.app" />
...
```

It's also possible to do it in UI, though set it up in **ide.genera.xml** works more reliable in my case.

Answer (score 2):

This was the fix for me:

WebStorm > Preferences > Tools > Web Browsers:

1. Change "Path" of Chrome to `/Applications/Google Chrome.app` (as opposed to `/Users/<Username>/Applications`)
2. Change "Default Browser" to "First listed" (and make sure the one you just changed is at the top of the list)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, looks like Webstorm is searching for an application, and is searching the folder /User/{Username}/Applications before searching /Applications.  I suspect Webstorm is using a system path to search, since a similar issue [has come up before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708660/remove-parallels-binding-to-a-command-line-open-app-command).

Short of finding (and changing) that path, can you try changing the way parallels shares applications with your Mac? In parallels, click on the VM's 'settings' button, then the 'Options' tab, then the 'Applications' page.  Try playing around with those settings - I suspect that unchecking "Share Windows applications with Mac" will solve your issue, though it may have unintended consequences (especially if you actually *want* applications to be available from the mac).